# Manipulating data in one table based on different table

Tags: r, data.table

I try to manipulate with columns of one table based on content of second table. I wrote following code:

```
mat1 = matrix(rnorm(10000*100), ncol=100)

pom1 = mat1

mat2 = matrix(sample(1:100, 10000*100, replace=T), ncol=100)

mat1 = cbind(mat1, mat2[,1:100])

for(i in 101:200){

  pom1[,i-100] = apply(mat1[,1:200], 1, function(x) x[which(seq(1:100)==x[i])])

}
```

I don't want to include mat2 into mat1 and the code is rather slowly. Is it possible to speed up this code by using `data.table` or in other way and not including mat2 into mat1?

In mat2 I've got integers which shows which element from mat1 I'd like to pass to pom1. For example if `mat2[2,5] = 8` then I'd like to put in `pom1[2,5] = mat1[2,8]`.

For example

```
mat1

V1  V2  V3  V4  V5

0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5

0.5 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1


mat2

V1 V2 V3 V4 V5

1  3  2  4  4

2  5  3  2  5
```

then in pom1 I'd expect

```
V1  V2  V3  V4  V5

0.1 0.3 0.2 0.4 0.4

0.4 0.1 0.3 0.4 0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are ordering per row and thus I don't think `data.table` would be suitable here. The fact that you are working with matrices (instead of `data.frame`s) makes the `apply` family quite efficient even on big data sets

This seem to work

```
pom1 <- t(sapply(seq_len(nrow(mat1)), function(x) mat1[x, mat2[x, ]]))
pom1
#       V1  V3  V2  V4  V4
# [1,] 0.1 0.3 0.2 0.4 0.4
# [2,] 0.4 0.1 0.3 0.4 0.1
```

I've tested it on your 1MM data set and it runs less than 1/10 of a second on average, so it should be fast enough for you I guess

```
mat1 = matrix(rnorm(10000*100), ncol=100)
mat2 = matrix(sample(1:100, 10000*100, replace=T), ncol=100)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(test = t(sapply(seq_len(nrow(mat1)), function(x) mat1[x, mat2[x, ]])))
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# test 61.62792 69.59457 77.88516 72.18077 76.10537 141.2513   100
```

Comment: Excellent, it's very fast and I don't need to copy one table into the other. Do you know why if I change matrix into data.frame it's not such fast? I'm a SAS user and handing with data is a big challange for me. Is there a good book about more advanced data handling tasks in R?